# Half-wave microstrip calculator contradicts simulation

Tags: transmission-line

I have tried to simulate a half-wave microstrip by this example. The end of the microstrip is open circuit. The substrate height and width are tested for 50 ohm as shown below.

But when I simulate this transmission line I get the impedance going around the open circuit circumference on the right side as you can see on the smith chart below.

How do I match this transmission line to 50 ohms? Is there a way?

[image]

[image]

[image]